# How to fetch dates between the from date and to date from a field which is stored as varchar in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table named payment and there is a field in it called next_due_date which holds a manually entered date value from the user in `yyyy-mm-dd` format and the type is VARCHAR. I tried

```
  select * from payment where next_due_date  >= '$strtdate' AND next_due_date  <= '$endDate';
```

`$strtdate` holds current date and `$endDate` holds the date value before 30 days from the current date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic issues - you are asking for records where the next_due_date is AFTER today AND where the next_due_date is BEFORE 30 days ago.  Think about that and you'll see why you get no records :)

You probably want something more like:

```
 select * from payment where next_due_date  <= '$strtdate' AND next_due_date  >= '$endDate';
```

Although that still looks 'weird' - probably because instead of:
"$strtdate holds **current** date and $endDate holds the date value **before 30** days from the current date."

Perhaps you want:
$strtdate holds 30 days **before** now and $endDate holds the **current** date.

THEN you can have:

from payment where next_due_date  >= '$strtdate' AND next_due_date  <= '$endDate';

Answer (score 0):

If you ensure that strtdate and enddate are in a yyyy-mm-dd format then the following should work:

```
select * from payment where next_due_date  <= '$strtdate' AND next_due_date <= '$endDate';
```

I assume you want to select records where the due date is within the start and end date range?